# Как отредактировать html код во многих файлах в php с sed?

Tags: php, html, sed

Нашел такие варианты `find ./<путь> -type f  -exec sed -i s'/<подстрока>/<замена>/g' {} \;`
Но оно даже не работает!

А хочу например на нескольких файлах поменять

```
<h1>Hello></h1>
<div class="test">
    <p>test</p>
```

на

```
<?php include file.php ?>
```

Comment: Если вас устраивает ответ, не забывайте голосовать и отмечать как верный.  Если не устраивает, вы можете получить уточнения в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Если задачу упростить до:

> Во всех файлах в каталоге `./yourpath` заменить содержимое
> начиная от строчки `<h1>Hello</h1>` до строчки
> `<p>test</p>` (именно таких, без пробелов перед
> или после) на `<?php include file.php ?>`.

То решение какое-то такое:

```
from='^<h1>Hello<\/h1>$'
to='^<p>test<\/p>$'
into='<?php include file.php ?>'
find ./yourpath -type f -exec sed -i "/${from}/,/${to}/c${into}" '{}' '+'
```

И на будущее:  «Не работает» ничего никому не говорит. Описывайте, что
именно происходит:  Как меняются файлы?  Какие статусы выхода у комманд?
Какие сообщения в диагностическом выводе?